# Она согласилась пойти со мной в ресторан, но только после окончания работы.

Tags: синтаксис

*Она согласилась пойти со мной в ресторан, но только **после окончания работы**.*

Определила выделенное как предложное сочетание, обстоятельство со значением времени. Верно?

+еще кое-что: я правильно понимаю, в предложении один глагол (*согласилась*) и это простое предложение? Как что рассматривается тогда то, что стоит после запятой (по грамматической терминологии)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это простое предложение, осложненное обособленным обстоятельственным оборотом со значением времени. В данном случае обособленный оборот относится к **присоединительным** синтаксическим конструкциям со значением дополнительного замечания, пояснения.

Присоединительные конструкции могут быть бессоюзными, но чаще они присоединяются с помощью различных союзов и союзных образований (в нашем случае это противительный союз НО и частица ТОЛЬКО со значением ограничения).